# Trying to resize a 3D array by flattening and the operands could not be broadcasted (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I have this toy data set I am playing with. I am trying to turn in into a list of arrays where each array in the number of units by the number of bins so (2,200) in this case.

So the whole thing should be (3,2,200). I keep getting instead the third dimension to just be an array of an array so it is actually (3,2,1).

To remedy this I have tried to use a loop to use the .flatten() which did nothing to the shape and then I tried to use.sum() which worked if I did it outside of the loop but when I did it within the loop I got this error:

```
data = {
    'trial_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'unit': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'psth': [np.random.rand(200) for _ in range(6)]
}

AE_0_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

trial_data = []

for trial_id, group in AE_0_df.groupby('trial_id'):
    unit_psth_array = group.pivot(index='unit', columns='trial_id', values='psth').values
    trial_data.append(unit_psth_array) # Flatten each element in the third dimension within your loop
    
for i in range(len(trial_data)):
    for j in range(len(trial_data[i])):
        trial_data[i][j] = trial_data[i][j].sum()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [36], line 17
     15 for i in range(len(trial_data)):
     16     for j in range(len(trial_data[i])):
---> 17         trial_data[i][j] = trial_data[i][j].sum()

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,) into shape (1,)
```

I am running Python 3.7.
[Jupyter notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvr9t.png)

Comment: Please add code from the screenshot to the question as text so that we don't have to retype it.

Comment: when i uploaded as text it said there was a formatting issue as well so still couldnt submitthe question

Comment: data = {
    'trial_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'unit': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'psth': [np.random.rand(200) for _ in range(6)]
}

AE_0_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

trial_data = []

for trial_id, group in AE_0_df.groupby('trial_id'):
    unit_psth_array = group.pivot(index='unit', columns='trial_id', values='psth').values
    trial_data.append(unit_psth_array)

# Flatten each element in the third dimension within your loop
for i in range(len(trial_data)):
    for j in range(len(trial_data[i])):
        trial_data[i][j] = trial_data[i][j].sum()

Comment: That's better, thanks! I don't know what was the problem - I edited your question myself and it worked. Hope someone will approve the changes soon. Going to take a look at your problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your task correctly, this is what you can do:

1. Use `pandas` `explode` to put all the values from numpy arrays as scalars into one column
2. Use `np.reshape` on `'psth'` column to collect it back in the right order. Order `A` does the trick and arranges scalars just the way they are in pivoted dataframe.

I think the problem was that pandas considered numpy array in a cell as a scalar (hence the shape `(3, 2)`) and I don't know if it's possible to convert it to 3d array from there.

Here's a simplified example to make sure everything ends up where it should be. I switched from random numbers to a shorter `arange` to make the result more readable:

```
data = {
    'trial_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'unit': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'psth': [np.arange(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10) for i in range(6)]
}

AE_0_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(AE_0_df)
```

```
   trial_id  unit                                      psth
0         1     1            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1         1     2  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
2         2     1  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
3         2     2  [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
4         3     1  [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
5         3     2  [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```

And then reshaping:

```
np.reshape(
    a=AE_0_df.explode('psth').reset_index(drop=True)['psth'].to_numpy(),
    newshape=(3, 2, 10),
    order='A'
)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This gives me an array of size (6,3) not size (3,2,10) which is what i am looking for

Comment: With your exact input data `data = { 'trial_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'unit': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'psth': [np.random.rand(200) for _ in range(6)] } AE_0_df = pd.DataFrame(data)` `np.reshape(...).shape` prints `(3, 2, 200)`. Do you use the same input?